# Joining Tables For Find the Playlists without any track of the genres “Latin”, “Rock” or “Pop”

Tags: mysql, join

I have a basic problem about create a query for Find the Playlists without any track of the genres “Latin”, “Rock” or “Pop”. I am really struggling with Joins some exercises I can do well but with this I can figure out.

I tried This:

```
SELECT p.PlaylistId as Playlist, p.Name
FROM Playlist p INNER JOIN PlaylistTrack pt ON p.PlaylistId = pt.PlaylistId 
INNER JOIN Track t ON pt.TrackId = t.TrackId
JOIN Genre g ON g.GenreId = t.GenreId
WHERE g.Name <> "Latin " AND "Rock" AND "Pop"
```

My Output are returning 1 value: AC/DC, and null values when I use LEFT JOIN.

This is my DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Genre (GenreId int PRIMARY KEY, `Name` CHAR(255) );
CREATE TABLE MediaType ( MediaTypeId int PRIMARY KEY, `Name` CHAR(30) );
CREATE TABLE Artist(ArtistId INT PRIMARY KEY, `Name` CHAR(255) ); -- LONG CHAR????
CREATE TABLE Album(AlbumId INT PRIMARY KEY, Title CHAR(120), ArtistId INT );
CREATE TABLE Track( TrackId int PRIMARY KEY, `Name` CHAR(255), AlbumId INT, 
 MediaTypeId INT, GenreId INT, Composer CHAR(220), Milliseconds int, Bytes INT, UnitPrice decimal(8,2)); -- UnitPrice number
CREATE TABLE Playlist(PlaylistId int PRIMARY KEY, `Name` CHAR(30));
```

If you are more interested and want to test this database that I build check this link, is a little dirty and need to be improve but commenting some rows will work.

> As I Said: My Output are returning 1 value: AC/DC, and null values when I use LEFT JOIN.

This is the expected value:

| PlaylistId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2, | Movies |
| 5 | TV Shows |
| 6 | Audiobooks |
| 7 | Audiobooks |
| 8 | Movies |
| 9 | Music Videos |
| 10 | TV Shows |
| 11 | Classical |
| 12 | Classical 101 - Deep Cuts |
| 13 | Classical 101 - Next Step |
| 14 | Classical 101 - The Basics |
| 15 | On-The-Go 1 |

I thought that this question was really easy. I dont understand why I can't figure out, can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Playlist 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM PlaylistTrack
                   INNER JOIN Track USING (TrackId)
                   INNER JOIN Genre USING (GenreId)
                   WHERE Playlist.PlaylistId = PlaylistTrack.PlaylistId
                     AND Genre.Name IN ('Latin', 'Rock', 'Pop') )
```

Comment: omg, thk u. How do you do that? What specific part of MySQL 8 Documentation is this? As you see I am struggling with old / resumed books.

Comment: @rubengavidia0x Study (correlated) subqueries and WHERE NOT IN <=> LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL <=> WHERE NOT EXISTS convertions. Of course on more simple tasks... You may also search and study such threads on this server.